# drawing two circles using Quartz CGContextFillEllipseInRect

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics

I am trying to draw two circles one inside of the other as the image below.

[image]

I have managed to draw one circle (the external one) nicely, but I am not sure how to add the 2nd circle on-top, and how to center it.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, 
                                     [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    //
     UIColor *theFillColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x6c83a6);
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents(theFillColor.CGColor));

    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(5.0,5.0,rect.size.width-10.0,rect.size.height-10.0);


    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //
    // INSIDE ?
    //

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
UIColor *theFillColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x6c83a6);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, theFillColor.CGColor);

CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(5.0,5.0,rect.size.width-10.0,rect.size.height-10.0);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke); // Or kCGPathFill

CGRect smallRect = CGRectInset(rectangle, 40, 40); // change 40 with the desired value
// You may change the fill and stroke here before drawing the circle
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, smallRect);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke); // Or kCGPathFill

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Hey sch, thank you for the answer, you should change in the answer above " CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);" on both cases, but other then that it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that. You may also use `kCGPathFillStroke` if you want to both fill and stroke.

Answer (score 5):

/*
Similar to the previous solution but somewhat simpler.
radius and start-end angle variables defined for clarity only.
*/

```
#define PI 3.14285714285714
float radius1 = 80;
float radius2 = 30;
float startAngle = 0;
float endAngle = endAngle = PI*2;
CGPoint position = CGPointMake(100,100);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
UIColor *theFillColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x6c83a6);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, theFillColor.CGColor);

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextAddArc(ctx, position.x, position.y, radius1, startAngle, endAngle, 1);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke); // Or kCGPathFill

// You may change the fill and stroke here before drawing the circle
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextAddArc(ctx, position.x, position.y, radius2, startAngle, endAngle, 1);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke); // Or kCGPathFill

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: you can you the `M_PI` define

Answer (score 1):

Swift

```
func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0)
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 94, alpha: 242).CGColor)

let theFillColor: UIColor = UIColor(hue: 0, saturation: 100, brightness: 80, alpha: 204)
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, theFillColor.CGColor)

let rectangle: CGRect = CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, rect.size.width-10.0, rect.size.height-10.0)
CGContextBeginPath(context)
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle)
CGContextDrawPath(context, CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke)

let smallRect: CGRect = CGRectInset(rectangle, 40, 40)

CGContextBeginPath(context)
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, smallRect)
CGContextDrawPath(context, CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke)
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.0

```
    let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.setLineWidth(4.0)
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 94, alpha: 242).cgColor)

    let theFillColor: UIColor = UIColor(hue: 0, saturation: 100, brightness: 80, alpha: 204)
    context.setFillColor(theFillColor.cgColor)

    let rectangle: CGRect = CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 5.0, width: rect.size.width-10.0, height: rect.size.height-10.0)
    context.beginPath()
    context.addEllipse(in: rectangle)
    context.drawPath(using:CGPathDrawingMode.fillStroke)

    let smallRect: CGRect = rectangle.insetBy(dx: 40, dy: 40)

    context.beginPath()
    context.addEllipse(in: smallRect)
    context.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.fillStroke)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```