# Drawing crosshairs with iOS CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics

How does one draw a crosshairs in an iOS app?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5); // yellow line
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 40.0, 40.0); //start point

    // Crosshairs go here?!?!?!?
    // What do I fill in?

    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context); 
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect); 
}
```

See example image below.

[image]

Comment: Have you look at the Quartz 2D Programming Guide? All you need is two lines and a circle.

Comment: Yes, I read it, but was getting shapes, not lines. I had to move on to something else and thought I'd ask. Guess that is discouraged. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you get started in seeing what you are missing. You are very close. Add an ellipse and you'll be done but as others have suggested, a simple quick look at the `Quart2d` programming guide or any `Quart2d` tuts will show all of this and more.

[Drawing a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684006/drawing-two-circles-using-quartz-cgcontextfillellipseinrect)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 20, 20);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 40, 20);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 30, 10);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 30, 30);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

Comment: Hey that's great, thanks for helping! I just added 
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(23.8, 14.4, 12, 12)); Now I can make the values relative. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome and a little friendly advice; IMO, the reason for all the down-votes is the wording of your question. Next time try to explain what you have tried and the result you expected without making it sound like a "do my homework" question. People love to help out here but only for specific questions that show research has been done. Happy coding!